# AFNetworking 2.0 Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1011 "Request failed: internal server error (500)

Tags: ios, web-services, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I am trying to convert my code to AFNetworking 2.0 with sub classing AFHTTPRequestOperationManager . Here is my code

```
+ (NSAFNetwokingRequestManager *)sharedClient {
    static NSAFNetwokingRequestManager *_sharedClient = nil;

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _sharedClient = [[self alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:GET_CAR_BRAND]];
    });
    return _sharedClient;
}
- (instancetype)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    self = [super initWithBaseURL:url];
     if (self) {
    self.responseSerializer = [AFXMLParserResponseSerializer serializer];
    self.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"application/soap+xml"];
    self.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
    [self.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/soap+xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];
}

    return self;
}
- (void)requestBrandcompletion:(NSAFNetwokingRequestManagerCompletionBlock)completion {
    NSString *soapRequest=@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
    "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
    "<soap:Body>\n"
    " <CarBrandExt xmlns=\"http://www.nohausystems.nl/\" />\n"
    "</soap:Body>\n"
    "</soap:Envelope>\n";
    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",[soapRequest length]];
    [self POST:GET_CAR_BRAND parameters:Nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
          [formData appendPartWithHeaders:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8", @"Content-Type", msgLength, @"Content-Length", nil] body:[soapRequest dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    } success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        if (completion) {
            completion(YES, responseObject);
        }
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        if (completion) {
            completion(NO, nil);
            NSLog(@"Unable to fetch record error %@ with user info %@.", error, error.userInfo);
        }
    }];
}
```

I am getting this error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1011 "Request failed: internal server error (500).  Can any one tell me what am i doing wrong here ? 
Getting this response :

```
{ status code: 500, headers {
    "Cache-Control" = private;
    "Content-Length" = 509;
    "Content-Type" = "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Thu, 13 Mar 2014 12:59:45 GMT";
    Server = "Microsoft-IIS/7.5";
    "X-AspNet-Version" = "2.0.50727";
    "X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET";
} }
```

Comment: Without looking at your code, error 500 is a server error, did you look your server's logs ?

Comment: The Same Web service is working fine with older version of AFNetworking

Comment: So i guess there is some problem with my implementations.

Comment: what about setting content type for the requestserializer `[self.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/soap+xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];` ?

Comment: plus I recommend to install a web debugging proxy like fiddler or charles to check the web traffic. You can then easily compare the working and the non-working request.

Comment: @Thorsten Thanks for your reply let me try that.

Comment: try this tutorial 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/59255/afnetworking-2-0-tutorial

Answer (score 2):

In your code you have:

```
[self POST:GET_CAR_BRAND parameters:Nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
          [formData appendPartWithHeaders:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8", @"Content-Type", msgLength, @"Content-Length", nil] body:[soapRequest dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

which defineds content-type as "text/xml", while the server is clearly expecting "application/soap+xml". You should try changing that part of the code to:

```
[self POST:GET_CAR_BRAND parameters:Nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
          [formData appendPartWithHeaders:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"application/sopa+xml; charset=utf-8", @"Content-Type", msgLength, @"Content-Length", nil] body:[soapRequest dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

## Updated suggestions:

Try adding:

```
[self.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

in the end of your `- (instancetype)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url` method.

If this doesn't help, I would suggest doing some more detailed network request debugging. You could e.g. set up [AFNetworkActivityLogger](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworkActivityLogger) to log the request/response information to the console.

Comment: I gave a more detailed look into it (I'm also quite new to AFNetworking 2.0) and updated the answer. Please try if that works.

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought, careful while you are using `BASEURL` with `AFNetworking`. If you are supplying the exact endpoint url to `AFNetworking` it might fail.

For eg:

You have an endpoint **`URL = http://myweb.com/api.php`**

In the above case if you are using `AFNetworking`, the **`BASEURL != URL`** whereas it should be something like `BASEURL=http://myweb.com/` and while calling for any request supply **`URL = api.php`**. `AFNetworking` appends the **BASEURL + URL** and creates a whole endpoint url.

Though the above answer might not be correct for your case. But in case it helps in taming other problem, or may be in your case too.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The "Request failed: unacceptable content-type: application/soap+xml" error is generated by

```
- (BOOL)validateResponse:(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response
                    data:(NSData *)data
                   error:(NSError * __autoreleasing *)error
```

method of AFHTTPResponseSerializer in case of unexpectable MIME type of response.

You can fix it with following code

```
self.responseSerializer = [AFXMLParserResponseSerializer serializer];
NSSet *set = self.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes;
self.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [set setByAddingObject:@"application/soap+xml"];
```

or modifying AFXMLDocumentResponseSerializer - add "application/soap+xml" to acceptable content types:

```
- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) {
        return nil;
    }

    self.acceptableContentTypes = [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects:@"application/xml", @"text/xml", @"application/soap+xml", nil];

    return self;
}
```

Following will not solve this problem I guess

```
[self.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/soap+xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];
```

There is not enough information to understand why do you have ""Request failed: internal server error (500)." I you will post correct and incorrect requests we will try to help you.

Comment: I do not think `[self.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/soap+xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];` could solve any of your problems. I have updated the answer please check.

Comment: Thanks That solve my problem for application/soap+xml but still getting internal server error ..

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :

```
[self.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/soap+xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
```

Comment: I've the same problem, when i apply your solution my project crashes by giving "this class is not key value coding compliant for the key 'Accept' ". Do you have any idea/solution for that? Thanks in advance.